# DAX Measure to Calculate Total Yearly Forecast by Snapshot Period

Tags: dax, forecast

I want to recreate a sumifs dax **measure** (not calculated column) to Sum Yearly Totals for each snapshot period (less than or equal to selected slicer Month End) by (forecast)month and Productcategory

In Excel this would be accomplished with the following sumifs function [=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$97,$A$2:$A$97,B2,$C$2:$C$97,C2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6rZd.png)

That is sum amount if reporting period equals value of month in current table row and category equals value of category in current table row

Table fields:
Snapshot Date (range from 31JAN2020 to 31DEC2020 by month end)

Forecast for Month (range from 31JAN2020 to 31DEC2020 by month end)

Sub Category (bikes, coats)

Amount (number actual sales mtd or projected count of sales)

Type (Actual or projection) actual sales amount to date, or projected for each month to end of year

Snapshot Date,Forecast for Month,Sub Category,Amount,Type,Expected Result fo 31MAR2020
1/31/2020,1/31/2020,Bikes,3,Actual,133
1/31/2020,2/29/2020,Bikes,7,Projection,138
1/31/2020,3/31/2020,Bikes,11,Projection,0
1/31/2020,4/30/2020,Bikes,20,Projection,0
1/31/2020,5/31/2020,Bikes,10,Projection,0
1/31/2020,6/30/2020,Bikes,11,Projection,0
1/31/2020,7/31/2020,Bikes,20,Projection,0
1/31/2020,8/31/2020,Bikes,20,Projection,0
1/31/2020,9/30/2020,Bikes,2,Projection,0
1/31/2020,10/31/2020,Bikes,9,Projection,0
1/31/2020,11/30/2020,Bikes,18,Projection,0
1/31/2020,12/31/2020,Bikes,2,Projection,0
1/31/2020,1/31/2020,Coats,1,Actual,111
1/31/2020,2/29/2020,Coats,8,Projection,136
1/31/2020,3/31/2020,Coats,10,Projection,0
1/31/2020,4/30/2020,Coats,17,Projection,0
1/31/2020,5/31/2020,Coats,12,Projection,0
1/31/2020,6/30/2020,Coats,1,Projection,0
1/31/2020,7/31/2020,Coats,11,Projection,0
1/31/2020,8/31/2020,Coats,4,Projection,0
1/31/2020,9/30/2020,Coats,16,Projection,0
1/31/2020,10/31/2020,Coats,10,Projection,0
1/31/2020,11/30/2020,Coats,10,Projection,0
1/31/2020,12/31/2020,Coats,11,Projection,0
2/29/2020,1/31/2020,Bikes,3,Actual,133
2/29/2020,2/29/2020,Bikes,17,Actual,138
2/29/2020,3/31/2020,Bikes,7,Projection,0
2/29/2020,4/30/2020,Bikes,17,Projection,0
2/29/2020,5/31/2020,Bikes,11,Projection,0
2/29/2020,6/30/2020,Bikes,11,Projection,0
2/29/2020,7/31/2020,Bikes,18,Projection,0
2/29/2020,8/31/2020,Bikes,17,Projection,0
2/29/2020,9/30/2020,Bikes,3,Projection,0
2/29/2020,10/31/2020,Bikes,13,Projection,0
2/29/2020,11/30/2020,Bikes,9,Projection,0
2/29/2020,12/31/2020,Bikes,12,Projection,0
2/29/2020,1/31/2020,Coats,15,Actual,111
2/29/2020,2/29/2020,Coats,7,Actual,136
2/29/2020,3/31/2020,Coats,15,Projection,0
2/29/2020,4/30/2020,Coats,11,Projection,0
2/29/2020,5/31/2020,Coats,1,Projection,0
2/29/2020,6/30/2020,Coats,12,Projection,0
2/29/2020,7/31/2020,Coats,9,Projection,0
2/29/2020,8/31/2020,Coats,13,Projection,0
2/29/2020,9/30/2020,Coats,2,Projection,0
2/29/2020,10/31/2020,Coats,16,Projection,0
2/29/2020,11/30/2020,Coats,19,Projection,0
2/29/2020,12/31/2020,Coats,16,Projection,0

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible measure that emulates the sumifs expression.
It work at the level of the single row and returns BLANK() if more than one row is in the current filter context

```
Result = 
VAR SelectedMonth =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Snapshot[Forecast for Month] )
VAR SelectedSubCategory =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Snapshot[Sub Category] )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ISBLANK ( SelectedMonth )
            && NOT ISBLANK ( SelectedSubCategory ),
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( Snapshot[Amount] ),
            REMOVEFILTERS ( Snapshot ),
            Snapshot[Snapshot Date] = SelectedMonth,
            Snapshot[Sub Category] = SelectedSubCategory
        ) + 0
    )
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you that got me 90% of the way there but I have to explicitly filter to [Sub Category] = "Actual" or [Sub Category] = "Projection" to calculate actuals to date plus remaining projections.  Please note there are other Sub Categories the [Sub Category] column as well 9 (eg. current_forecasts) and I do not have a slicer for on the page for [Sub Category]